# How to divide array array with specific pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need divide array: Into N ( **N is number of new arrays** ) arrays with certain patern.

Array is dynamic and values can change.

This is illustrated example what i want to do:

[image]

**This is real life example what i trying to do:**[image]

I need divide  one array in this pattern and create N arrays: In examples i created 2 arrays but now imagine that i want create 99 arrays

[image]

Comment: Thanks then i done it without pictures no one understand my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work..

```
var array = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
var results = devideArray(array,2);

function devideArray(array, count){
    var result = [];
    for (var i=0; i<count; i++){
        result[i] = [];
    }
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        result[i%count].push(array[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```